# javascript validate form with two or more dropdown lists

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I'm designing a html form that has two dropdown lists and a few text inputs. I intend to validate using javascript but i'm not able to validate the dropdown lists.

I have tried and tested the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XFtBD/2/) but cannot figure out how i can use this for two or more dropdown lists. My code looks like this

```js
<script>


 function ValidateForm(){
   var names = document.forms["myForm"]["names"].value;
   var month = document.forms["myForm"]["month"].value;
   var year = document.forms["myForm"]["year"].value;
   

    if (names == null || names ==""){
     lert ("name cannot be empty");
     return false;
     }

    
    if(month == null || month ==""){
     alert ("month must be selected");
     return false;
     }
    
    if(year == null || year ==""){
     alert ("year must be selected");
     return false;
     }




}
   
</script>
```

```html
<html>

<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name = "myForm" action = "" onsubmit="return ValidateForm()" method = "post">
 

 Name: <input name ="names" type = "text" size = "55" maxlength = "100"><br>
 Month: <select id ="selectmonth" name="month">
  <option value="">-select month-</option>
  <option value="January">January</option>
  <option value="February">February</option>
    <option value="March">March</option><p>
  <option value="April">April</option><p>
  <option value="May">May</option><p>
  <option value="June">June</option><p>
  <option value="July">July</option><p>
  <option value="August">August</option><p>
  <option value="September">September</option><p>
  <option value="October">October</option><p>
  <option value="November">November</option><p>
  <option value="December">December</option><p>
 </select><p>

Year: <select name ="year">
  <option value = ""> -select year-</option>
  <option value = "2015"> 2015 </option>
  <option value = "2016"> 2016 </option>
  <option value = "2017"> 2017 </option>
 </select><p>
<input name = "add_person" type="submit" value = "submit">
</form>

<body>
</html>
```

How can i have the form validate everything on clicking the submit button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After noticing .. you are missing an `a` in the `alert`.

Like this:

```js
 function ValidateForm(){
     var names = document.forms["myForm"]["names"].value;
     var month = document.forms["myForm"]["month"].value;
     var year = document.forms["myForm"]["year"].value;
      if (names == null || names ==""){
       alert ("name cannot be empty"); //<-- here was lert()
       return false;
      }
      if(month == null || month ==""){
       alert ("month must be selected");
       return false;
      }
            if(year == null || year ==""){
       alert ("year must be selected");
       return false;
      }
    }
```

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name = "myForm" action = "" onsubmit="return ValidateForm()" method = "post">
 

 Name: <input name ="names" type = "text" size = "55" maxlength = "100"><br>
 Month: <select id ="selectmonth" name="month">
  <option value="">-select month-</option>
  <option value="January">January</option>
  <option value="February">February</option>
    <option value="March">March</option><p>
  <option value="April">April</option><p>
  <option value="May">May</option><p>
  <option value="June">June</option><p>
  <option value="July">July</option><p>
  <option value="August">August</option><p>
  <option value="September">September</option><p>
  <option value="October">October</option><p>
  <option value="November">November</option><p>
  <option value="December">December</option><p>
 </select><p>

Year: <select name ="year">
  <option value = ""> -select year-</option>
  <option value = "2015"> 2015 </option>
  <option value = "2016"> 2016 </option>
  <option value = "2017"> 2017 </option>
 </select><p>
<input name = "add_person" type="submit" value = "submit">
</form>
```

After replacing for alert.. it works..

### EDIT 1:

Regarding the JSFiddle as you suggested in the comment.

I've simplified it and made it work like you desire.

```js
function fun()
{
 var mainCard = document.getElementById("cardtype");
 var mainCardValue = mainCard.value;
 var otherCard = document.getElementById("othercard");
 var otherCardValue = otherCard.value;
 if (mainCardValue == "selectcard") {
    alert("Please select a card type");
 } else if (otherCardValue == 'selectcard') { 
    alert("Please select a secondary card type");
 }
}
```

```html
<label class="paylabel" for="cardtype">Card Type:</label>
<select id="cardtype" name="cards">
     <option value="selectcard">--- Please select ---</option>
     <option value="mastercard">Mastercard</option>
     <option value="maestro">Maestro</option>
     <option value="solo">Solo (UK only)</option>
     <option value="visaelectron">Visa Electron</option>
     <option value="visadebit">Visa Debit</option>
</select>
<select id="othercard" name="cards">
     <option value="selectcard">--- Please select ---</option>
     <option value="mastercard">Mastercard</option>
     <option value="maestro">Maestro</option>
     <option value="solo">Solo (UK only)</option>
     <option value="visaelectron">Visa Electron</option>
     <option value="visadebit">Visa Debit</option>
</select>

<input type="button" onclick="fun()" value="click here">
```

Comment: Thanks Joel....How can one use the JSFiddle that i point out above to validate two dropdown lists with one submit button?